# Consulta SQL para obtener campos en Java

Tags: java, mysql

¿Cómo sería exactamente una consulta SQL acorde con el siguiente método?

El problema es que con las tres tablas no consigo sacarlo correctamente. Lo único que habría que modificar sería la consulta.

**-mostrarDatosPedido(int numeroPedido)**. Este método consultará la base de datos y mostrará del pedido pasado como parámetro, los productos que incluye (codigo y nombre) y la cantidad pedida de cada uno ellos.

**Tablas de la actividad:** 
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Código:**

```
public static void mostrarDatosPedido(int numeroPedido)
throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException {

    ConectarSingleton conexion = new ConectarSingleton();
    Connection con = conexion.getConexion(); //añadir excep.

    ResultSet rs = GestionClassic.consultar("select * from pedidos where numeroPedido='"+numeroPedido+"'");
    while(rs.next()) {
        System.out.println(rs.getInt(1)+"\t"+rs.getDate(2)+"\t"+rs.getDate(3)+"\t"
                +rs.getDate(4)+"\t"+rs.getString(5)+"\t"+rs.getString(6)+"\t"+rs.getInt(7)+"\t"); 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En la consulta debes poner tras el select los campos que quieres ver, es decir, codigoProducto, nombreProducto y cantidadPedida haciendo un join con las tablas detallepedidos y productos. En este caso no necesitas usar la tablas pedidos ya que en las otras dos tienes toda la información necesaria.

El resultado sería algo así:

```
"SELECT detallespedidos.codigoProducto, productos.nombreProducto, detallesPedidos.cantidadPedida
FROM detallespedidos INNER JOIN productos ON(detallespedidos.codigoProducto = productos.codigoProducto)
WHERE detallespedidos.numeroPedido = " + numeroPedido + ";"
```

Comment: Convendría también que use consultas preparadas para prevenir ataques de inyección SQL, o que un usuario descontento provoque un verdadero caos en los datos.